# Error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."

Tags: django, mongodb, django-admin, djongo

I'm using Django with Mongodb using Djongo Connnector. With Django 2.2 everything is working fine but When I'm upgrading my Django version > 3 , I'm getting - Error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." while doing any create operation in Django admin. Its happening in models where foreign keys are there , for foreign key it is showing - Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
What can be the issue. If I'm downgrading my Django version to 2.2 , everything seems working. [Click here to see error reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqoZJ.png)

Models.py

```
from djongo import models
# Create your models here.

'''Country model starts from here'''
class Country(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (u'0', u'InActive'),
    (u'1', u'Active'),
    )
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=("Country Name"))
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=("Country Code"))
    phonecode = models.CharField(max_length=5, verbose_name=("Phone Code"))
    status = models.CharField(default=1, max_length=1,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name="Status")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Country"
        verbose_name_plural = "Country"
        db_table = 'am_country_master'
'''Country model ends from here'''

# State Model Starts here
class State(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (u'0', u'InActive'),
    (u'1', u'Active'),
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=("Country Name"))
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=("State Name"))
    status = models.CharField(default=1, max_length=1,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name="Status")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "State"
        verbose_name_plural = "State"
        db_table = 'am_state_master'
# State Model Ends here

# City Model Starts here
class City(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (u'0', u'InActive'),
    (u'1', u'Active'),
    )
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE , verbose_name=("State Name"))
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=("City Name"))
    status = models.CharField(default=1, max_length=1,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name="Status")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "City"
        verbose_name_plural = "City"
        db_table = 'am_city_master'
# City Model Ends here
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Country , City , State

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(State)
admin.site.register(City)
```

While saving in State Model---

'''Formdata'''

1. csrfmiddlewaretoken:
   LUG0IqBMV9dqcgRKTyByZmeibUxbj4JNGMUqr5K6hleCxcklR6hSJQf9i0O3zqbw
2. country: 62f0b55d735d49fda2279de9
3. state_name: New Delhi
4. status: 1
5. _save: Save

'''Retrieved queryset for Country'''

```html
<select name="country" required="" id="id_country">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="62f0b55d735d49fda2279de9" selected="">India</option>

  <option value="62f20a4e2dd3bd1c3e533cce">Netherlands</option>

</select>
```

Comment: I don't see any backwards incompatible changes from version 2.2 to 3 that are related to form fields. I suggest that you look into what is the form data that is trying to be saved (you can get it from POST request). Also, it would be useful to know what is the retrieved queryset for the choices - you can get this by debugging and inspecting the FK field. Also, `models.py` please

Comment: @vinkomlacic When I'm writing my custom function to save data in this model , Its working perfectly. This problem I'm getting when I'm using Django admin to save in any of the registered models having foreign key.

Comment: Hey @shivam, did you solve this? If so, how?